# JQuery Datatable Editor not updating row after successful edit

Tags: java, jquery, datatables, server-side, jquery-datatables-editor

I am using JQuery Datatable Editor with Server Side processing using Java Servlet. Editing a row works fine but the updated data is not being shown in the table.
 The edit is successful and I am able to see the JSON object for the updated row in the browser console.

```
var editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
            ajax:  '/fda/intranet/translationNew/TranslationFileServ',
            table: '#example',
            idSrc:  'id',
            fields: [
                { label: 'Id', name: 'id',type:  "readonly" },
                { label: 'In Current File',  name: 'inCurrentFile',type:  "readonly"  },
                { label: 'en_us',  name: 'en_us',type:  "readonly"  },
                { label: 'translatedTo',  name: 'translatedTo',type:  "readonly"  },
                { label: 'translation',  name: 'translation', type: 'textarea'  }

                // etc
            ]       
        } );
```

Comment: Can you show your Datable Script here:

Comment: I tried to add it..but stack overflow says its too much code. i was only able to add a part of the javascript code

Comment: I am not sure about how to share the rest of my Javascript ....please let me know if there is an easier way